# Notice on line 0

Tags: php, opencart, ccavenue

I am using [AJAX Quick Checkout](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15580) for open cart  1.5.5.1.
I receive following notice while I integrate it with CCAvenue.

[Live Link](http://www.eklavya.in/pitara/index.php?route=checkout/checkout)

```
Notice: Undefined index: comment in /home/eklavya/public_html/pitara/catalog/controller/payment/ccavenuepay.php on line 0
Notice: Undefined index: comment in/home/eklavya/public_html/pitara/catalog/controller/payment/ccavenuepay.php on line 0
```

I also replaced my ccAvenue version it still sows this notice. My ccavenuepay.php is encoded as shown in image if i edit it shows 'File is corrupt message'.

[image]

Comment: Post your source code, in addition to a screenshot

Comment: Is Ioncube or ZendEncoder installed on server ? (Which one this ccavenue use)

Comment: Yes IONCUBE is there on server. It's CCAvenue McPG.

Comment: I have hidden notice currently by using error_reporting.